# Understanding the implications of using UnpooledByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT in Flink with Cassandra sinks

Tags: cassandra, apache-flink, netty, flink-connector-cassandra

I am in the process of upgrading Flink applications from JDK 8 to JDK 11, and these applications use Cassandra sinks. During this process, I encountered an issue with the Flink cluster running out of direct memory after restarting the applications multiple times. It appears that direct memory is not being reclaimed when stopping the job, which may indicate a memory leak. This memory issue does not occur when the cluster runs on Java 8.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
```

I am using below version of flink and flink-connector-cassandra.

`Flink cluster version`: 1.14.3

`flink-connector-cassandra_2.11`: 1.14.3

I found a related Flink issue ([FLINK-17493](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-17493)), where a workaround was suggested: modifying the custom Netty options to use `UnpooledByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT` as the byte buffer allocator. This solution seems to be working in my case.

However, I would like to better understand what exactly this change does and if there might be any potential implications or side effects in the long run. Furthermore, are there any other solutions available for addressing this direct memory issue? If so, could you please suggest them?